# Popup a new Window with ActionResult and JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying, with absolutely no success, to open details about a technician in a new popup window through JQuery.

cshtml:

```
function Details(id) {
    $.post('TechniciansProductivityDetails', { techId: id }, function (result) {
        newpage = result;
        window.open('TechniciansProductivityDetails', 'popUpWindow', 'height=400, width=650, left=300, top=100, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#anchor1").click(function () {
        if ($(this).find("dataListItemType1")) {
            var id = $(".dataListItemType1").first().attr("id");
            Details(id);
        }
    });
});
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TechniciansProductivityDetails(string techId)
{
    return View("TechniciansProductivity/TechniciansProductivityDetails", GetTechniciansProductivityDetailsModel(techId));
}
```

Expected behavior: `ActionResult` gets called and `techId` is populated with the expected technician Id.

Resulting behavior: `ActionResult` gets called twice. At the first time, `techId` is correctly called, but nothing happens on the client side. At the second time, `techId` is `null`, but the popup window opens without any data.

Comment: Is TechniciansProductivityDetails a `HttpPost` or `HttpGet` action?

Comment: What is the use of `newpage` variable if the intention to open the details in popup?

Comment: It should be post. Do I have to specify with the `[HttpPost]` data annotation?

Comment: None. I just copied this from somewhere. Don't actually understand this part. I'm new with Front-End...

Comment: If you don't specify the action accepts both Verb.

Comment: Ok. I added `[HttpPost]`. But my problem remains...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a action if is not specified explicit verb then it accept both type of request whether it is GET or POST. but when a action method is decorated with either `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` attribute then the action method accepts only those request method which define by attribute.

Now why it is called twice :
Since you have called action `TechniciansProductivityDetails` in $.post and window.open that's why it is invoked twice. Now if intention here is to show the details only then change it as follows :

```
    [HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult TechniciansProductivityDetails(string techId)
    {
        return View("TechniciansProductivity/TechniciansProductivityDetails", GetTechniciansProductivityDetailsModel(techId));
    }


function Details(id) {
       window.open('@Url.Action("TechniciansProductivityDetails")?techId=' + id, 'popUpWindow', 'height=400, width=650, left=300, top=100, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes');
    });
}
```

Comment: Change the code to `'@Url.Action("TechniciansProductivityDetails")?techId=' + id'`. Try it again with updated code.

Comment: Ok, I'll take this as my solution, since I didn't specify from the beginning that I wanted a POST. In fact, a Get could be more useful in this case.

Comment: Yes, Get is more meaningful here as you have to show the details in popup.